# The symbol h for class numbers

Tags: terminology, number-theory

We use $h_K$ conventionally to denote the class numbers of number fields $K$.

But I have never thought why the letter $h$ was used for it.

Why and who used $h$ for the class number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on MO once. The notation goes back to Dirichlet. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17062/why-is-h-the-notation-for-class-numbers

Comment: Haupt(form)! It's very persuasive. Thank you!